# Login authentication reactjs using UniversalRouter and React-started-kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, universal-react

How can i check login in all route, using React-started-kit, Universal Router, i was using Cookie and action in route, but not working

Comment: Hi nguyễn hoàng, elaborate more about what you want to achieve and what errors you get, are you trying to add access restriction in your app?

Comment: @mamounothman i was try to check login in all route , using React-started-kit: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit , i using Cookie in route for check but not working, I don't know what to do :(

Comment: I suggest you check some tutorials about react authentication and how to protect react routes: good tutorial: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/ this might not be directly helpful for you but it will give you idea how to add authentication to your app, also checkout passport.js lib, I sure you will find a way to integrate it with your stack.